# Не формируется нормально URL

Tags: php

Формировал урл для парсинга и тут начал запрашивать информацию с сайта.В результате 404.Почти понял в чем проблема благодаря NotePad++.*Я даже не знаю как это описать*[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если присмотреться - будет видно что нотепад думает что все дальше **films/** не ссылка.В случае с вторым урлом - все как раз наоборот.Ответ от сервера есть и все счастливы.
P.S - Висман был прав.Реально есть невидимое что-то[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S.S код:

```
       function ParseKeys($val){
         $tr = trim($val);
         for ($i=1; $i < 10 ; $i++) { 
        $form = "http://kinoroomes.pw/films/$tr/?page=$i";
            ....
 $cats = file('../temp/cats.txt');
foreach ($cats as $value) {
 $res[] = ParseKeys($value);
 }
   //вызывает функцию для парсинга
```

Comment: Вы бы ссылки эти сюда скопировали как есть. Там может невидимые символы есть, которые и делают ссылку невалидной

Comment: @ВОРОН редактор исправляет ссылки

Comment: @Maksym, вы уж тогда на ссылку смотрите в HEX редакторе, чтобы было понятно, что не так в хвосте ссылки.

Comment: Покажите код для формирования ссылок.

Comment: @sba `$tr = trim($val);
     for ($i=1; $i < 10 ; $i++) { 
       $form = "http://kinoroomes.pw/films/$tr/?page=$i";
     
       $html = file_get_html("http://kinoroomes.pw/films/$tr/?page=$i"); ...`

Comment: а `$val` что хранит? попробуйте перед `trim` написать `$val = 'new';`, если не поможет, попробуйте `new` сразу написать в адресе, если также будет ошибка - значит в адресе `http://kinoroomes.pw...` что-то невидимое есть.

Comment: Предоставленный фрагмент кода не раскрывает происхождение значения переменной $val. Очень похоже что проблема именно в этом значении.

Comment: @Maksym, добавьте в вопрос весь код, отвечающий за генерацию URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пересохраните ваш файл `cats.txt` в формате **UTF-8 без BOM**. На картинке в вашем вопросе видна метка **BOM** состоящая из трех байтов `EF BB BF`.

[Маркер последовательности байтов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2)